# openscad - align a shape with a path defined by two points

Tags: openscad

I have a function:

```
function knotAng(a,s) =
    [(sin(a)+(2*sin(2*a)))*s,
     (cos(a)-(2*cos(2*a)))*s,
     sin(3*a)*s];
```

I am placing a number of objects along a path where a=0 to 359 and s is constant

I want to orient the objects so they follow the path described by knotAng(a-step,s) and knotAng(a,s)

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Tips_and_Tricks#Drawing_.22lines.22_in_OpenSCAD

Comment: post this as an answer and I'll except it - just what I needed - completely missed this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tips&Tricks page, section '[Drawing "lines" in OpenSCAD](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Tips_and_Tricks#Drawing_.22lines.22_in_OpenSCAD)' of the user manual shows how to rotate "lines" in 3D space by calculating the minimal rotation matrix as described in section '[Minimum rotation problem](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Tips_and_Tricks#Minimum_rotation_problem)'.